# Perl command not found

Tags: perl, unix, fedora

I am new to Unix. I am trying to Run a Perl script on Fedora 14 machine.

I wrote the script and saved it in a file called PerlOne.pl and changed its permission to 755. This is what it has

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "hello";
```

I tried to run it so I got

```
/usr/bin/perl : bad interpreter no such file or directory.
```

So I checked if I already have perl by typing

```
perl -v
```

I got

```
perl: command not found
```

Is it possible that Fedora comes with no perl? or am I doing something wrong? if yes, then how can I install perl?

Any help would be appreciated =)

Comment: What's the results of: `which perl`?

Comment: I wonder what will `yum --showduplicates list perl` show.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run: `yum list all | grep perl`

If it doesn't show perl then you haven't got it installed.

So, install it using: `yum install perl`. You may need to run it as root.

Comment: It didn't show perl. How to run it as root ?

Comment: If you are part sudoer list then: `sudo yum install perl` will work. Otherwise, `sudo su -` give root password then run `yum install perl`.

Comment: It's better practice to only use `sudo`, so I'd use the first option.

Comment: great! how to get out of root ?

Comment: By the way, for making a user a sudoer on Fedora, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4405/how-to-make-fedora-user-a-sudoer

Answer (score 2):

Try searching `Perl` with :

```
find / -path '*bin/perl'
```

And copy-paste here the output of `echo $PATH`, I suspect it to be wrong.

**EDIT** seems like some Fedora distros don't put `perl` by default, see http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=254537

Comment: It's not in `/usr/bin`, there should be at least a symlink in there.  So it's more likely to not be installed rather than the PATH being wrong.

Comment: See my edited post

Comment: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/fedora/.local/bin:/home/fedora/bin

Comment: yep. Installed it and it works now

Answer (score 2):

You can determine whether Perl is installed on your system by using the package manager that your system uses to install and keep track of software.  In RedHat distros, the package manager is RPM.

So...  To list all installed packages that have perl in their name, try:

```
rpm -ql | grep -i perl
```

(I'm suggesting using grep because IIRC rpm's internal queries are case sensitive.)  If you see no results, then Perl probably isn't installed.

To install it, you'll probably use [YUM](http://linux.die.net/man/8/yum):

Comment: Yes you're right. It wasn't installed. Thanks mate

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
find / -type f -name '*perl*' 2>/dev/null
```

This is a wider search scope than that proposed by Gilles Quenot, but it will only return files (not directories) and also remove any "Permission denied" errors from the output so it is clearer.

Look for the result found under a '/bin/...' or '/sbin/...' directory.